# Craft CMS on LAMP (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS) /admin not loading

Tags: admin, install

I'm completely new to Craft CMS, I come from the Drupal/Wordpress corner.

On my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with PHP, MySQL, Apache and Composer installed.

Using Composer I installed craftcms to `/var/www/html/testsite/`

In `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` I changed the DocumentRoot to point to `/var/www/html/testsite/web`

In the browser I point to `127.0.0.1` and I get the Welcome page.

When I click on **Go to your control panel** I am taken to `127.0.0.1/admin` with the following error:

> Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server.

In my `/var/www/html/testsite/.env` file I have `PRIMARY_SITE_URL=http://localhost/testsite/web/`

What am I missing? (I have looked at other similar questions here but did not find anything helpful for my specific case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close.

The `DocumentRoot` is where in the filesystem Apache will "start" serving files for that virtual host (server name). Basically it's where the "home page" of the server lives.

So if `localhost` is the name of the vhost, your "home page" would be at `http://localhost` and you can get to the admin/dashboard of the site at `http://localhost/admin/login`.

If for some reason your rewrites aren't working, you can still access the dashboard of the site like `http://localhost/index.php?p=admin/login`.

The `testsite/web` isn't part of the URL because that's where in the filesystem Apache will "start" looking but it is part of the `DocumentRoot`. Basically anything below the root is in the URL and anything above is not accessible.

In your `.env` file, set your `PRIMARY_SITE_URL` to `http://localhost`.

Also see the [installation docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/installation.html).

Comment: Thanks for this, so I think my rewrites are currently not working because using http://localhost/index.php?p=admin/login I was able to get to the login form, but after logging in I get taken to http://127.0.0.1/admin/dashboard which again displays a "Not Found" error (and I have enabled mod_rewrite).

Comment: Make sure you're accessing the site via "localhost" and not the IP Address?

Comment: Same behavior with "localhost"

Comment: Hmm I may be missing the overwrite directive in the virtual host, let me test that.

Comment: That was it, since I used the default apache 000-default.conf file it was missing the directory specific directives. Working now. Thansk!

Comment: @BrokenCode excellent!

Answer (score 1):

First you need to enable mod_rewrite in your ubuntu system.

Create new .htaccess file in the root location of your project.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php
</IfModule>
```

After this you can see your admin at this location
http://localhost/testsite/admin/login

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. When you say "root location" do you mean the /web folder of craft cms? Also, since I modified apache DocumentRoot to point to /var/www/html/testsite/web do I still need to point the browser to http://localhost/testsite/web/admin/login? I would expect that I don't need to do that?

Comment: Not inside web folder you need to create outside of the web folder